# Choice property on $N$ subsets; how to extend it to $2N$ subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $C := \{1,\dots,c\}$ that we can call colors. Suppose there exist $2N$ subsets of $C$: $S_1, S_2 \dots, S_{2N}$ that we can call color lists. These color lists may be empty (but not all of them).

Now suppose that we have the following property:

1. For any choice of $N$ color list,  it's possible to choose $k\ge1$ colors such that at least $N-k+1$ chosen color lists contains  *all* of these $k$ colors, and no restriction for the others lists.
   In other words, either some lists agree on a lot of colors, or a lot of lists agree on a few colors.

I want to prove that we can do the same thing for all the color lists, that is:

2. It is possible to chose $k\ge1$ colors of $C$ such that $2N-k+1$ lists contains all of these $k$ colors and no restriction for the others.

As an element of context, $c = o(N/\log N)$ but I'm not sure it should matter too much beyond the fact that $c<<N$.

I already had a few thoughts that may be helpful:

- If we start from a given set of $N$ list, under what conditions we can change one of the list and replace it by an other one, while keeping the same $k$ colors?
- If we suppose it's not possible for the $2N$ lists, it is in particular the case for $k=1$, meaning that one of the lists is empty or there is a partition of $C$ in at least two sets; and color list are subsets of one of these.
- If there are $\lambda$ empty list, then the first property must be true, a.k.a. for any choice of non-empty $N-\lambda$ lists, they agree on $\lambda +1$ colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c\le N$ and (1) holds, then (2) holds.

**Proof.** I show the contrapositive: if $c\le N$ and (2) fails, then (1) fails.

Let $C=\{1,\dots,c\}$ be the set of colors and let $S_1,\dots,S_{2N}\subseteq C$.
For $i\in C$ let $A_i=\{j\in\{1,\dots,2N\}:i\notin S_j\}$, the set of lists omitting color $i$.

The failure of (2) simply means that $|\bigcup_{i\in K}A_i|\ge|K|$ for all $K\subseteq C$. By [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) this system of inequalities is equivalent to the existence of an injective map $f:C\to\{1,\dots,2N\}$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$, that is $i\notin S_{f(i)}$, for all $i\in C$. Now any set of $N$ lists that includes the lists $S_{f(1)},\dots,S_{f(c)}$ will witness the failure of (1).

**Remark.** The problem can be stated a bit more cleanly in terms of matrices of $0$'s and $1$'s. The following statement is slightly generalized; the original question was for $M=2N$. The proof is the same as above, using Hall's theorem.

Let $\mathbf A$ be a $c\times M$ matrix of $0$'s and $1$'s. If $c\le N\le M$, and if every $c\times N$ submatrix of $\mathbf A$ contains a $k\times(N-k+1)$ submatrix of $1$'s for some $k$, then $\mathbf A$ contains a $k\times(M-k+1)$ submatrix of $1$'s for some $k$.

Comment: If I understand well the construction, $S_{f(i)}$ is a list not containing the color $i$, and the point is that the Hall's theorem is able to find $c$ distinct lists such all the colors are missing at some point in one of them. How does that contradicts the first property?

Comment: Consider any set of $N$ lists that includes $S_{f(1)},\dots,S_{f(c)}$. Now, whatever set of $k$ colors you choose, call them $i_1,\dots,i_k$, at most $N-k$ of your $N$ lists will contain all the chosen colors, because none of the $k$ lists $S_{f(i_1)},\dots,S_{f(i_k)}$ can be used.

Comment: Likewise, if the second property fails, then for any set $K$ of $k$ colors there are at most $2N-k$ lists containing all the colors in $K$, so least $k$ lists miss one of the colors in $K$, i.e., belong to $\bigcup_{i\in K}A_i$. This all seems quite straightforward to me, so I must have misunderstood the question. What am I missing?

Comment: Now I see what puzzled me in your answer. It is quite straightforward indeed!